# Applying a Rolling Window on Overlapping Time Measurements

Tags: matlab, window, filtering, data-processing

I have data recorded from a device (250-Hz sampling device, ~100K measurements total so about 400 seconds worth). I want to create (overlapping) windows of 512 (~2 seconds) or 1024 (~4 seconds) measurements each, perhaps in ~0.5 second intervals. I'm using Matlab.

Is there a particular way to accomplish this goal? I imagine I want to use a filter to accomplish this goal? Would it change if I wanted to apply, say, a Hann window as well?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) to process possibly overlapping blocks with an arbitrary function

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks to me as though blockproc is focused specifically on image processing. I also don't think it actually allows for overlapping blocks. Otherwise, that would be the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: I think it does. You have to set `blocksize` appropriately (one entry `1`, second entry the window step) and use the `'BorderSize'` option to produce the desired window size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your data be a row vector. You can use [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) if you:

- choose the "`blockSize`" argument as `[1 S]`, where `S` is window step;
- use the `'BorderSize'` option to set borders `[0 B]`. Window length will be `S+2*B`;
- set the `'TrimBorder'` property to `false`;
- define an appropriate function to apply to each window data.

For example, say you a length-5 window with step 3, and you want the sum of all elements in each window:

```
>> x = 1:12;
>> y = blockproc(x, [1 3], @(t) sum(t.data), 'Bordersize', [0 1], 'TrimBorder', false)
y =
    10    25    40    42
```

where

```
%// 0+1+2+3+4 = 10
%// 3+4+5+6+7 = 25
%// 6+7+8+9+10 = 40
%// 9+10+11+12+0 = 42
```

Note the zero padding at the initial and final windows. To avoid that, include an adequate amount of initial zeros in the data, choose data size appropriately, and discard initial and final output values:

```
>> x = 1:14;
>> y = blockproc([0 0 x], [1 3], @(t) sum(t.data), 'Bordersize', [0 1], 'TrimBorder', false)
y =
     3    15    30    45    60    27
```

where

```
%// 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
%// 4+5+6+7+8 = 30
%// 7+8+9+10+11 = 45
%// 10+11+12+13+14 = 60
```

Comment: In the first example, why do you pre-define `x`? Doesn't `x` in `@(x) sum(x.data), ` represent each block from the first argument in the `blocproc`  function call?

Comment: @kkuilla Yes, I was defining data `x` and not using it. Thanks! Corrected now